# Hadoop: compress file in HDFS?

Tags: compression, hadoop

I recently set up LZO compression in Hadoop.  What is the easiest way to compress a file in HDFS?  I want to compress a file and then delete the original.  Should I create a MR job with an IdentityMapper and an IdentityReducer that uses LZO compression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you write a MapReduce job that, as you say, just uses the Identity mapper. While you  are at it, you should consider writing the data out to sequence files to improve performance loading. You can also store sequence files in block-level and record-level compression. Yo should see what works best for you, as both are optimized for different types of records.

Answer (score 21):

For me, it's lower overhead to write a [Hadoop Streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html) job to compress files.

This is the command I run:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar \
  -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
  -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true \
  -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
  -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
  -input <input-path> \
  -output $OUTPUT \
  -mapper "cut -f 2"
```

I'll also typically stash the output in a temp folder in case something goes wrong:

```
OUTPUT=/tmp/hdfs-gzip-`basename $1`-$RANDOM
```

One additional note, I do not specify a reducer in the streaming job, but you certainly can.  It will force all the lines to be sorted which can take a long time with a large file.  There might be a way to get around this by overriding the partitioner but I didn't bother figuring that out.  The unfortunate part of this is that you potentially end up with many small files that do not utilize HDFS blocks efficiently.  That's one reason to look into [Hadoop Archives](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hadoop_archives.html)

Comment: why "cut -f 2" instead of, say, "cat" ?

Comment: The input to the mapper is a key and a value separated by a tab. The key is the byte offset of the line in the file and the value is the text of the line. `cut -f 2` outputs only the value.

Comment: How can i compress the folder in hdfs?

Comment: The answer below actually uses the cat command, which is the correct answer.

Comment: Above command gives extra "tab" character at the end of each line of the compressed output.

Answer (score 5):

The streaming command from Jeff Wu along with a concatenation of the compressed files will give a single compressed file. When a non java mapper is passed to the streaming job and the input format is text streaming outputs just the value and not the key.

```
hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar \
            -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
            -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
            -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true \
            -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
            -input filename \
            -output /filename \
            -mapper /bin/cat \
            -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat \
            -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat
hadoop fs -cat /path/part* | hadoop fs -put - /path/compressed.gz
```

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand the commands. The first one produces the output in gzipped file but the actual file isn't in the *.gz format so the second command is to rename it?

Comment: No, the first command generates the compressed *.gz **part** files (many of them). And the second command is for concatenating those part files together into a single 'compressed.gz' file.

Comment: Above command gives extra `tab` character at the end of each line of the compressed output

Answer (score 4):

This is what I've used:

```
/*
 * Pig script to compress a directory
 * input:   hdfs input directory to compress
 *          hdfs output directory
 * 
 * 
 */

set output.compression.enabled true;
set output.compression.codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec;

--comma seperated list of hdfs directories to compress
input0 = LOAD '$IN_DIR' USING PigStorage();

--single output directory
STORE input0 INTO '$OUT_DIR' USING PigStorage();
```

Though it's not LZO so it may be a bit slower.

Comment: Does this compress each individual file in the input directory, or does the compression treat all the files as one big file and compress that, then output potentially many fewer files? If the latter case, is there a way to specify how much data pig should try to compress at a time, e.g. 3Gb at a time?

Comment: Yes, it will load an entire input directory into a single alias and output as ${OUT_DIR}/part-m-*.bz2. If you want a 3Gb input directory then control IN_DIR

Answer (score 4):

@Chitra
I cannot comment due to reputation issue

Here is everything in one command: Instead of using the second command, you can reduce into one compressed file directly

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar \
        -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
        -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
        -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true \
        -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec \
        -input /input/raw_file \
        -output /archives/ \
        -mapper /bin/cat \
        -reducer /bin/cat \
        -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat \
        -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat
```

Thus, you gain a lot of space by having only one compress file

For example, let's say i have 4 files of 10MB (it's plain text, JSON formatted)

The map only is giving me 4 files of 650 KB
If I map and reduce I have 1 file of 1.05 MB

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old thread, but if anyone following this thread (like me) it would be useful to know that any of following 2 methods gives you a `tab` (\t) character at the end of each line

```
 hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar \
      -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
      -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true \
      -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
      -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
      -input <input-path> \
      -output $OUTPUT \
      -mapper "cut -f 2"


hadoop jar share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar \
        -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
        -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
        -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true \
        -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec \
        -input /input/raw_file \
        -output /archives/ \
        -mapper /bin/cat \
        -reducer /bin/cat \
        -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat \
        -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat
```

From this [hadoop-streaming.jar adds x'09' at the end of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620256/hadoop-streaming-jar-adds-x09-at-the-end-of-each-line), I found the fix and we need to set following 2 parameters to respecitve delimiter you use (in my case it was ,)

```
 -Dstream.map.output.field.separator=, \
 -Dmapred.textoutputformat.separator=, \
```

full command to execute

```
hadoop jar <HADOOP_HOME>/jars/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.4.11.jar \
        -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
        -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
        -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true \
 -Dstream.map.output.field.separator=, \
 -Dmapred.textoutputformat.separator=, \
        -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec \
        -input file:////home/admin.kopparapu/accenture/File1_PII_Phone_part3.csv \
        -output file:///home/admin.kopparapu/accenture/part3 \
 -mapper /bin/cat \
        -reducer /bin/cat \
        -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat \
        -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat
```

Answer (score -4):

Well, if you compress a single file, you may save some space, but you can't really use Hadoop's power to process that file since the decompression has to be done by a single Map task sequentially. If you have lots of files, there's [Hadoop Archive](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/hadoop_archives.html), but I'm not sure it includes any kind of compression. The main use case for compression I can think of is compressing the output of Maps to be sent to Reduces (save on network I/O).

Oh, to answer your question more complete, you'd probably need to implement your own RecordReader and/or InputFormat to make sure the entire file got read by a single Map task, and also it used the correct decompression filter.

Comment: Hadoop has integrated compression libraries, see http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/06/parallel-lzo-splittable-compression-for-hadoop/.

Comment: Interesting. I thought you were talking about input being compressed, not compressing the output, sorry. Do you care about the sorting of the data in the output file? You could easily just use the filesystem APIs and wrap the FSDataOutputStream in the LZO compression filter if you don't care about the sorting of the output file. If you do, then FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput() and setOutputCompressorClass(). It's right in the Javadoc, found it in 10 seconds via Google.