# How to compress Hadoop directory to single gzip file?

Tags: hadoop, compression, hdfs, gzip, hadoop-streaming

I have a directory that contains lots of files and sub directories that I want to compress and export from hdfs to fs.

I came across this question - 
[Hadoop: compress file in HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153087/hadoop-compress-file-in-hdfs)
, but it seems like it's relevant only to files, and using hadoop-streaming and the GzipCodec gave me no success with  directories.

What is the most efficient why to compress HDFS folder into single gzip file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't `gzip` a directory even on Unix's FS. You need to first convert it to a `tar/har` or something like that and then perform compression.

Comment: @philantrovert Of course, but do you have any advice about how to do so?

Comment: I'd suggest writing a Java program using the apache commons Api. It has classes like `TarArchiveOutputStream` which you can look into.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For a quick, dirty solution, for those of you who don't want to use hadoop-streaming or any MapReduce job for it, I used [FUSE](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_hdfs_mountable.html) and then preform actions on it as traditional filesystem.
Pay attention that you might don't want to use this as a permanent solution, only for a quick win :) 
Further reading: 
* https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html 
* http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec

Answer (score 1):

You will need a library or roll your own code to make a tar stream out of files in a directory structure. You can use zlib to compress the tar stream to make a standard .tar.gz file.

The two tidbits I can provide here if you want to merge the results of multiple such tasks are: 1) you can concatenate gzip streams to make valid gzip streams, and 2) you can concatenate tar streams to make a valid tar stream *if* you remove the final 1024 zero bytes from the non-final tar streams.