# Compress files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, compression, hdfs

I'm a newbie to compression in hadoop. We have a lot of old files sitting in HDFS that needs to be compressed. Can someone please tell me how this can be done. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153087/hadoop-compress-file-in-hdfs

Comment: You need to add more information. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]