# How to uncompress file while loading from HDFS to S3?

Tags: hadoop, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, distcp, s3distcp

I have csv files in `lzo` format in `HDFS` I would like to load these files in to s3 and then to snowflake, as snowflake does not provides lzo compression for csv file format, I am required to convert it on the fly while loading these files to s3.

Comment: If you're using s3distcp, you can specify output compression codec https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html?

Comment: @mazaneicha thanks for the response, can I use s3distcp outside of EMR?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a Lambda function that decompresses the files upon landing on s3, here is a link that gets you there:

https://medium.com/@johnpaulhayes/how-extract-a-huge-zip-file-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket-by-using-aws-lambda-and-python-e32c6cf58f06

Comment: sorry, this is not an option for my use case, as this is part of a pipeline, can't add another step for Lambda. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9572706/2704032) helped me to convert from `.lzo_deflate` to required snowflake compatible output format:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar \
  -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
  -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true \
  -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
  -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
  -input <input-path> \
  -output $OUTPUT \
  -mapper "cut -f 2"
```